# why do i need to return the head in a linked list?c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
NODE* InsertAtHead(NODE* &head, int val){
    NODE *tmp = new NODE;

    //create a new node
    if (tmp == NULL)
        exit(1);

    //Initialize the new node
    tmp->data = val;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    //Insert by changing links
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;         //update head
    return head;
}
```

Why in the end we need to put return head?

Comment: Well you've told your compiler you're going to return a `NODE*` with your function header...

Comment: Have you tried not returning head to see what happens?

Comment: `if (tmp == NULL)` Note: that in modern `c++` new does not return NULL on failure. it throws `std::bad_alloc` Example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc

Comment: no not yet...im still learning about it im a beginner in data structure..if i wrote the function header NODE InsertAtHead(NODE* &head,int val)       what will it return ?? or just none?

Comment: Not quite...if you don't want to return anything in your function, you can use the `void` keyword for the return type.

Comment: Taking your question literally, you _don't need to_ return the head.  That is something done in the code you're showing, but it could be implemented differently too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked list (when people say linked list they usually mean single linked list) has a link to the next node and no link to the previous one. So imagine if you return a node that is in the middle of list, you could get to next one and next one all the way to the end, this is good. Where you have a problem is that you will not be able to go to the previous node unless you have link to it, which would make it double linked list, or have pointer to the `head` first node in list which will serve as a start.

In your case you are pushing nodes onto the front of the list thus your code is pushing previous head to next and making new node a head node.

EDIT:
The `head` should be pass by reference. `val` should be passed by value. Why? For `head` we need an address of it so we could make a link to it. For `val` if we would pass it by reference, the address might be reused in caller function and we do not want our data to change.

Comment: I don't agree that "linked list" is shorthand for "Single Linked List".  The later is a type of the former.

Comment: everytime i want to insert a val or delete i need to pass it by reference right? or it wont make the change?

Comment: @dorman i memt when people say linked list they usually mean single linked list

Comment: In your answer you're correct that Linked List is talking about singly-linked in this example, but I disagree that "*when people say linked list they usually mean single linked list*." After all, the [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), the (arguably) most used linked list in c++ is doubly linked...

Comment: @scohe001 fixed

Comment: @MonicaKhoury I have added explanation in regards to pass by value and pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

The linked list you have is a singularly linked list. It only has references for next so you can only iterate to the end. If you have a pointer to the beginning you can get to everything, but if you have a pointer to the middle, you have no knowledge of the beginning.

In this function you are prepending, which creates a new beginning. If you don't return the new beginning then the calling function will have no knowledge of this element.

This is of critical impotance as you are using new to allocate memory and if it is not freed there will be a memory leak. It can't be freed unless the calling function has this pointer.

Comment: but there's pass by reference ;)

Comment: Btw in a doubly linked list (prev and next pointers) you can get away with not returning, but it would make everything else painful.

Comment: u mean that after the function is executed i need to free the pointer to go back to the head of the list??

Comment: everytime i want to insert a val or delete i need to pass it by reference right? or it wont make the change?

Comment: No. Just when you want to delete an element or clean up the list. Every new needs to have a corresponding delete.